Could not find ffmpeg executable, tried "/srv/linux-x64/ffmpeg"
I am trying to run my docker image on AWS EC2 Instance. However, I am having a trouble with the image file. When I run a task in AWS ECS, it says:
Could not find ffmpeg executable, tried "/srv/linux-x64/ffmpeg", "/srv/app/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/linux-x64/ffmpeg" and "/srv/app/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/linux-x64/ffmpeg"

This is my Dockerfile:
FROM node:latest as server
WORKDIR /srv/app
COPY ./server/package*.json ./
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 'ffmpeg'
RUN npm install
COPY ./server .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:latest as client
WORKDIR /srv/app
COPY ./client/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./client .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:latest as production
WORKDIR /srv/app
RUN mkdir /public
COPY --from=server /srv/app/dist ./
COPY --from=client /srv/app/dist ./public
ENV NODE_ENV=production
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["node", "app.js"]

This is my package.json:
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/ffmpeg": "^1.0.7",
    "@types/fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.24"
  }

This is how I used ffmpeg in my code:
import ffmpegPath from '@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg';
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg';
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath.path);

Please help me fix this error.

Each FROM line in the Dockerfile starts over with a new clean image.  You only install ffmpeg in the first build stage.  You're presumably trying to use it from the final image; you need the apt-get install ffmpeg invocation in the final build stage for it to be present there.

Note that this is a docker build issue, that you should be able to test and verify locally before ever getting to the point of deploying to AWS.

I put the RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 'ffmpeg' in each FROM but it is still showing the same error:
Could not find ffmpeg executable, tried "/srv/linux-x64/ffmpeg", "/srv/app/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/linux-x64/ffmpeg" and "/srv/app/node_modules/@ffmpeg-installer/linux-x64/ffmpeg"
Did I miss anything here?

@pdoherty926 was right. You have to install ffmpeg to all the images or at least the images that are using it and the production one. But in addition, you also have to change your code from:
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath.path);
to
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath('/usr/bin/ffmpeg');
This code might give you errors when running in your machine in dev mode but it should work when you run the docker image on EC2 Instance.

As @David Maze said in a comment above, you're only installing ffmpeg in the first image.
One alternative way to address installing the package in each image would be to create a "base" image which adds common config, packages, etc. on top of node:latest and is then extended by each of your component images. This arguably adds some runtime bloat, so you could either only use it in the images where it's required or use it throughout and potentially move other common environment and config setup into it.
It would look something like:
# Dockerfile
FROM node:latest AS base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 'ffmpeg'

FROM base AS server
WORKDIR /srv/app
COPY ./server/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./server .
RUN npm run build

FROM base AS client
WORKDIR /srv/app
COPY ./client/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./client .
RUN npm run build

FROM base AS production
WORKDIR /srv/app
RUN mkdir /public
COPY --from=server /srv/app/dist ./
COPY --from=client /srv/app/dist ./public
ENV NODE_ENV=production
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["node", "app.js"]



I edited my Dockerfile as yours but after pushing it to ECR and running a task from ECS cluster, it is still showing the same error. Did I miss anything?

For those using Alpine, the apt-get equivalent is apk: RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache ffmpeg
